# Gradle javadoc task fails with unexpected text

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

I'm getting the following error:

```
/Users/rin/Development/Java/Libs/JavaClearHttp/src/main/java/com/levelrin/javaclearhttp/record/Record.java:22: error: unexpected text
 * The {@link this#toString()} method can be useful for viewing all information at once.
       ^
```

The javadoc looks like this:

```java
/**
 * It's responsible for providing the request and response records.
 * The {@link this#toString()} method can be useful for viewing all information at once.
 */
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword caused the problem.
I use the class name instead, and the problem was gone.

Before:

```java
{@link this#toString()}
```

After:

```java
{@link Record#toString()}
```